# How to force VSCode to format newly created document using .editorconfig

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, editorconfig

I'm building vscode extension which generates files with some content.
What i'm trying to do, is force vscode to format those newly created files with rules defined in .editorconfig.

I have tried to do the following:

```
fs.writeFile(file.name, file.content, (err) => {
          if (err) { errors.push(err.message) }

          let edit: vscode.WorkspaceEdit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
          const { activeTextEditor } = vscode.window;
          const fileUri = vscode.Uri.file(file.name);

          vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(fileUri).then((td) => {
            vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeFormatDocumentProvider', fileUri, { tabSize: 50, insertSpaces: true, insertFinalNewline: true }).then((edits: vscode.TextEdit[]) => {
              if (edits !== undefined) {
                let formatEdit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
                formatEdit.set(fileUri, edits);
                vscode.workspace.applyEdit(formatEdit);
                vscode.workspace.saveAll();
              }
            },
              error => console.error(error));
```

Unfortunately i have faced two issues:

1. i don't know how to retrieve .editorconfig properties since `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('editor')` is not the same as defined in .editorconfig file
2. This approach not always work sometimes format isn't applied at all

Does anyone know how to solve it?